# How to avoid infinite [null] JSON response from zmq recv()

Tags: python, json, zeromq

If the server program is sending a JSON response of size 100 MB for every request, zmq recv method is printing **[null]**
infinitely,should i set some socket options to make sure that the heavy responses are sent through the wire properly.

[image]

**Server Program**

```
c = zmq.Context()
s = c.socket (zmq.REP)
s.connect(port)

while True:
    message = s.recv()
    s.send('[JSONSTRING_OFSIZE_100MB]')
```

**Client Program**

```
import zmq

if __name__=="__main__":
     c = zmq.Context()
     s = c.socket(zmq.REQ)
     s.connect ("tcp://localhost:6555")
     s.send('some request string')
     print s.recv()
     pass
```

**Broker Program**

```
context = zmq.Context()
frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
backend = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)

for aClient in clientList:
    frontend.bind(aClient)

for aServer in serverList:
    backend.bind(aServer)

zmq.proxy(frontend, backend)
```

Assume that the server program is sending some MB's of data in JSON format using the socket.send(JSONSTRING).

Comment: Isn't that the JSON `null` value? Its not the transport, its the json object you are sending.

Comment: No the json object has proper strings when the response is sent, only when the response is received , it is null and it keeps printing infinitely.

Comment: I'm skeptical. 100Meg will take multiple minutes to print and that's well beyond my attention span. I can't test it here because I don't have your json object but it would be worth checking it a second time. In server program, you could write the json to a temporary file just before sending to make sure you have the object you think you have.

Comment: I downloaded your scripts, tweaked them a bit to make them runnable and replaced the server send line with `s.send(json.dumps(['I am a string.'] * 10000000))` and "I am a string" was printed a hundred million times. I cannot reproduce your error and am quite certain its your json doc, not zmq.

Comment: i am looking into it, will let you know soon, if there is an error in the JSON response, i will let you know, thanks @tdelaney